# Spring - Required part 'file' is not present

Tags: javascript, angular, spring, spring-boot, xmlhttprequest

I am sending "multipart/form-data" to my backend. In postman it works but sending it from my frontend does not. The backend does not accept the MultipartFile from my frontend because

> "required part 'file' is not present"

**Backend:**

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> createDogProfilePicture(@PathVariable(value = "dogId") Long dogId, @RequestPart(name = "file") MultipartFile file) {
    Optional<Dog> dog = dogService.createDogProfilePicture(dogId, file);

    if(dog.isEmpty()) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
 }
```

**Frontend**

```
postDogProfilePic(dogId: string, file: File): Observable<any> {

let data = new FormData();
data.append("file", file);

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.jwtService.getTokenFromCookies(),
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------058354453416487168263921'
  })
};

return this.http.post(this.url, data, httpOptions)
}
```

**Postman Payload (Succeeds)**

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpg"
<dog.jpg>
```

**Frontend Payload (Fails)**

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
[JFIF Image Data]
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so apparently my backend did not accept the HTTP-Header in my post request.

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

I just removed it and now its working.